# Issue On The Linq Query

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do a very simple task with `Linq` and already stuck. It's really horrible but I guess, it's better to know using this post. I've two tables. One is **Products** and another is **Ratings**. Here is the demo script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProductName] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Details] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL
 )

INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Details], [CategoryID]) VALUES (1, N'Denim', 1200, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Details], [CategoryID]) VALUES (2, N'Denim 2', 220, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Details], [CategoryID]) VALUES (3, N'Pringles', 240, NULL, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Details], [CategoryID]) VALUES (4, N'Pringles 2', 260, NULL, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Details], [CategoryID]) VALUES (5, N'Pringles 3', 240, NULL, 2)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ratings](
    [AutoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserRating] [float] NOT NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Ratings] ([AutoId], [ProductId], [UserRating]) VALUES (4, 2, 1.5)
INSERT [dbo].[Ratings] ([AutoId], [ProductId], [UserRating]) VALUES (5, 4, 2.5)
INSERT [dbo].[Ratings] ([AutoId], [ProductId], [UserRating]) VALUES (6, 1, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[Ratings] ([AutoId], [ProductId], [UserRating]) VALUES (7, 2, 2.5)
```

And the output should be the following:

```
ProductId - ProductName - User Rating
1 - Denim - 5
2 - Denim 2 - 2
3 - Pringles - 0
4 - Pringles 2 - 2.5
5 - Pringles 3 - 0
```

This is the rating system of a project and I am trying to get the above output using `Linq`. With the following `Sql`, I got the result:

```
SELECT m.ProductId, m.ProductName, ISNULL(SUM(k.UserRating) / COUNT(k.ProductId), 0) AS 'User Rating' FROM Products m
LEFT JOIN Ratings k ON k.ProductId = m.ProductID
GROUP BY m.ProductID, m.ProductName
```

Unfortunately, with the following `Linq`, I get only the rating details that exist in the **Ratings** table:

```
var con = (from c in db.Ratings
           join d in db.Products on c.ProductId equals d.ProductID into ps
           from rt in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
           group new { c, ps } by new { rt.ProductID, rt.ProductName } into g
           select new ProductRating
           {
              ProductId = g.Key.ProductID,
              ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
              Total = g.Sum(c => c.c.UserRating) / g.Count()
           }).ToList();
```

**Note:** My goal is to get the rating details (sum of a product's rating) that don't exist in the **Ratings** table (Should return '0' if no data) along with the ratings details that exist.

**Update 1 - Class ProductRating**:

```
public class ProductRating {
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
     public double Total { get; set; } //Property for the rating
  }
```

**Update 2 - Class Products and Ratings**:

```
 public partial class Products
 {
     public int ProductID { get; set; }
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
     public Nullable<double> Price { get; set; }
     public string Details { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Ratings> Rating { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class Ratings
 {
    public int AutoId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public double UserRating { get; set; }
 }
```

Used the following the `Linq` query and got this error - **The specified type member 'Rating' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported**:

```
 var con = db.Products.Select(c => new ProductRating
           {
              ProductId = c.ProductID,
              ProductName = c.ProductName,
              Total = c.Rating.Average(d => (double?)d.UserRating) ?? 0
           }).ToList();
```

**Update 3**: Now getting this error - **error 2016: The value specified for the condition is not compatible with the type of the member** and this is how I tried for the navigation property:

[image: Navigation Property]

**Note:** I've modified `Andrés Robinet`'s query and it worked though using the `Join`.

Comment: You've messed up the left and right parts of the left outer join in LINQ query. Don't you have navigation property, somethig like `public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }` in `Product` class? And what is the ORM used - e.g. LINQ to SQL, EF6, EF Core or?

Comment: I am using EF 6.0 and it has a property called `Total`. Updated in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start with the `Product`. Also, the order of your joins in your Linq expression is the opposite than in your SQL. And, the `group ... by ...` needs just `rt.UserRating` as the *value selector*

```
var con = (from d in db.Products
           join c in db.Ratings on d.ProductId equals c.ProductId into ps
           from rt in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
           group new { rt.UserRating } by new { d.ProductId, d.ProductName } into g
           select new ProductRating
           {
               ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
               ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
               Total = g.Sum(r => r.UserRating) / g.Count()
           })
           .ToList();
```

Also, this would break if `g.Count()` is zero. But you have a few choices anyways:

- Add more complexity to the query and pray for EF to be able to translate it into SQL

  ```
  select new ProductRating
  {
      ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
      Total = g.Count() > 0 ? (g.Sum(r => r.UserRating) / g.Count()) : 0
  }
  ```
- Redefine `ProductRating` or use a helper `DTO`,  so that it takes `Sum` and `Count` properties (calculate the average on-demand, let's say, you can still have a `Total` property)

  ```
  select new ProductRating
  {
      ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
      SumRating = g.Sum(r => r.UserRating),
      CountRating = g.Count()
  }
  ```

Comment: I've tried your solution @Andrés Robinet and it works perfectly. But I only get the rating values that exist in the `Ratings` table. Though trying to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
from c in db.Ratings
join d in db.Products on c.ProductId equals d.ProductID into ps
from rt in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

is the LINQ equivalent of the SQL `Ratings LEFT OUTER JOIN Products`, i.e. exactly the opposite of your SQL query.

While the LINQ query can be modified to match the SQL query, it doesn't make sense because EF provides a much better way which totally eliminates the need of using joins in the LINQ query - the so called navigation properties (see [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)).

Normally the `Product` class would have a collection navigation property

```
public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
```

representing the one to many relationship between `Product` and `Rating`, and the equivalent LINQ query using it would be simply:

```
var result = db.Products
    .Select(p => new ProductRating
    {
        ProductId = p.ProductId,
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        Total = p.Ratings.Average(r => (double?)r.UserRating) ?? 0
    }).ToList();
```

**Update:** In case you haven't set up correctly the relationship in the entity model, you could use the manual join equivalent of the above query by replacing the navigation property accessor with [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/join-operations):

```
var result = (
    from p in db.Products
    join r in db.Ratings on p.ProductId equals r.ProductId into ratings
    select new ProductRating
    {
        ProductId = p.ProductId,
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        Total = ratings.Average(r => (double?)r.UserRating) ?? 0
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it looks promising @Ivan Stoev. Right now, I am getting this error - **The specified type member 'Rating' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.** I've gone through the link and manually updated the `Product` class adding navigation property. Updated in the post.

Comment: Well, looking at your Update 2, the `public ICollection<Ratings> Rating { get; set; }` is definitely **entity navigation property**, so you shouldn't be getting that error. Except if it's not mapped correctly in the edmx (DataBase First) or fluent API/data annotations (Code First). Some part of the full picture is missing, and you are the only one having it.

Comment: I am using EF database first and hope, that doesn't make any difference. Though I've made the change manually in the class `Products`, will it be effective or need to do anything alternative?

Comment: There is a difference in this case though. You should not be doing it manually, but through relationship in edmx designer.

Comment: I've updated the post and included an image of how I am dealing with navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ statement has an inner join, whereas your SQL has a left join.

Comment: Yes. In `Linq`, I tried to use this **from rt in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()** for the `LEFT JOIN`. But didn't work.